# Struggling to sum values in one column, based on specific text criteria in another column for visible rows only in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

In Google Sheets I have a series of site names in Column A and then some irrelevant data from column B to R. Then I have values in column S and then "Valid" and "Invalid" text criteria in Column T. My plan is to provide a total value for "Valid" and "Invalid" criteria where the sites can then filter their respective sites and see what their "Valid" and "Invalid" totals are.

Any help will be appreciated.

I know that ***=sumif($T$6:$T,"Valid",$S$6:$S)*** do not work for filtered or hidden rows.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: Please see a Link to the sheet below...

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10EgTCiJVzcEp13dK0Ye1HJmt5hu8my4NkPMpxpVUmt0/edit#gid=0

Comment: the shared sheet has *restricted access*